# Seaborn barplot add horizontal line at different heights

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a barplot and I would like to add a horizontal line in each of the bars based on a pandas column value. I have seen examples of how to add a single horizontal line over all the bars but this is not what I am aiming for.

What I have tried so far is:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 3], [3, 6, 1], [4, 8, 3]], columns=["X", "Value", "Hor"])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.barplot(x="X", y="Value", data=df, color='green', ax=ax)
sns.barplot(x="X", y="Hor", data=df, color='green', linewidth=2.5, edgecolor='black', ax=ax)
```

[image]

This is relatively close to what I would like to have, but I only want the top edge and preferably dashed.

My question is twofold:

1. Is this the way to do this? By stacking two barplots on top of each other?
2. If this is the way, how can I adjust all the edges to fit what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the patches in your barplot, extract width and position and plot your values using plt.plot. Note that this will break if the dataframe is not sorted.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 3], [3, 6, 1], [4, 8, 3]], columns=["X", "Value", "Hor"])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.barplot(x="X", y="Value", data=df, color='green', ax=ax)

for ix, a in enumerate(ax.patches):
    
    x_start = a.get_x()
    width = a.get_width()
    
    ax.plot([x_start, x_start+width], 2*[df.loc[ix, 'Hor']], '--', c='k')
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great! For some incomprehensible (to me :)) reason, in my actual data I get an error because the ix goes to a value that is one more than the rows of the dataframe. I know this is probably tough to answer but would have even the faintest hint as to why that might be?

Comment: yes, hard to tell from a distance. You should generate the same number of bars as rows in your dataframe. This number, in turn, controls how high `ix` gets.

Comment: Oh well, I guess it will remain a mystery to me. I added a break (to my shame!). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using [`hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html) on your axis, e.g. when iterating over the rows of your data frame. The code would look like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 3], [3, 6, 1], [4, 8, 3]], columns=["X", "Value", "Hor"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.barplot(x="X", y="Value", data=df, color='green', ax=ax)

# iterate over range of number of rows
for i in range(len(df)):
    ax.hlines(y = df.Hor[i], xmin = i-0.5, xmax = i+0.5,
              color = 'black')
```

When you're plotting barplots, the x coordinates start at zero for the first bar with increments of one. This information can be used to assign `xmin` and `xmax` to `ax.hlines`, here in the form of `i` which goes from zero to the number of rows of your data frame minus one. You can customize `0.5` to your needs, depending on the 'width' of the desired line.

[image: Resulting plot]